# Не могу подключить DLE к MySQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, dle, vds

Я взял VDS, установил на неё апач, пхп, всё по вафле, как говориться.

Принялся устанавливать DataLifeEngine 13.1, в конце пишет 

`Access denied for user '[Пользователь]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Все данные правильные, подсоеденяюсь через локалхост.

Comment: Посмотрите доступ этого юзера к localhost. Возможно, у него доступ только к 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Нет, доступ к локальному хосту

Comment: Ну 127.0.0.1 тоже локальный адрес. Однако для mysql бывает критична такая разница

Comment: Знаю, но оба варианта не работают

Comment: Пытался через порт пробить - так же

Comment: Точно уверены, что данные верные? Тут просто DLE никак не при чём, у DLE всего лишь класс с функциями для упрощённой (и дырявой, но не суть) работы с базой. А mysqli отдал то, что отдал - пользователь неверный.

Comment: Так, ошибку исправил - Дело было в правах для пользователя, единственное что одного пришлось удалить, и создать нового с правами